# How to include numbers that show up only once and 0 times into this programs output?

Tags: javascript

I have this program that currently finds duplicates and prints them out using the dom in sections. I am editing this so that it also shows numbers that have not occurred in the input array at all and numbers that have only occurred once in the input array as well. Not including 0 as a number that has not occurred. Also setting a variable to be the max number range we check to see if a number appears or not in the input array. The sectioning of the output is working fine, I am essentially only adding numbers that only occurred 0 and 1 times into the output. I can't see how to do this correctly. Please assist. Thank You.

> Example array input
>   [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,5]
>
> Current Example output: (sections variable = 3):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>   2 - 8 times
>
> 3 - 7 times
>   1 - 6 times
>
> 7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times
>
> Desired Output: Example 1 (sections variable = 3. numbersrange = 9):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>   2 - 8 times
>   3 - 7 times
>
> 1 - 6 times
>   7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times
>
> 5 - 1 times
>   8 - 0 times
>   9 - 0 times
>
> Desired Output: Example 2 (sections variable = 3. numbersrange = 21):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>   2 - 8 times
>   3 - 7 times
>   1 - 6 times
>   7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times
>   5 - 1 times
>
> 8 - 0 times
>   9 - 0 times
>   10 - 0 times
>   11 - 0 times
>   12 - 0 times
>   13 - 0 times
>   14 - 0 times
>
> 15 - 0 times
>   16 - 0 times
>   17 - 0 times
>   18 - 0 times
>   19 - 0 times
>   20 - 0 times
>   21 - 0 times

```js
//Count how many times each number shows up

//const duplicateArr2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23];
//const duplicateArr1 = [5, 3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2];
//const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54];
//const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54,100,100,200,200,300,300];

//const duplicateArr2 = searchednumbers;
const duplicateArr2 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5]

const getArrayOfDuplicated = array => {
  const hash = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1, a), {});

  return Object.entries(hash)
    .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
    .sort(([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => bv - av)
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, `${k} - ${v} times`], [])
};

// given a number of items to be sectioned into a certain number of groups
// returns a list of length nGroups with the number of items in each group
// such that at least (nGroups - 1) groups contain an equal number of items
// eg. getGrouping(10, 2) -> [5, 5]
// eg. getGrouping(10, 6) -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
const getGrouping = (nItems, nGroups) => {
  if (nGroups > nItems)
    return Array(nItems).fill(1);
  else if (!(nItems % nGroups))
    return Array(nGroups).fill(parseInt(nItems / nGroups));
  else {
    let numberOfEqualGroups = nGroups - 1;
    var itemsPerEqualGroup;
    if (!(nItems % (nGroups - 1)))
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1)) - 1;
    else
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1));
    equalGroups = Array(numberOfEqualGroups).fill(parseInt(itemsPerEqualGroup));
    remainder = nItems - itemsPerEqualGroup * numberOfEqualGroups;
    return equalGroups.concat(remainder);
  }
}

// takes an array and formats it into sections according to grouping
// returns a string with a newline after each line and two new lines between sections
const formatGrouping = (array, grouping) => {
  var outputString = ""
  var linesDone = 0;
  for (var section = 0; section < grouping.length; section++) {
    for (var line = 0; line < grouping[section]; line++) {
      outputString += array[linesDone] + '<br>';
      linesDone += 1;
    }
    outputString += '<br>';
  }
  return outputString;
};

var numberOfSections = 3;
result = getArrayOfDuplicated(duplicateArr2);
document.getElementById("jsresultsoutput").innerHTML = formatGrouping(result, getGrouping(result.length, numberOfSections));
```

```html
<p id="jsresultsoutput"></p>
```

Comment: Why does your desired output include "9 times", "8 times", etc.? I thought you only wanted to show the numbers that appear 0 or 1 times.

Comment: the number of numbers that appear 0 times would be infinite - unless there's some given set of numbers to search for

Comment: @JaromandaX I think that's the "numbersrange" -- it means to only go up to that limit.

Comment: Where is `numbersrange` in the code?

Comment: The code is doing the opposite of what you say you want. The `filter()` call is only returning numbers that appear 2 or more times, not 0 or 1.

Comment: @Barmar - yeah, I didn't see that in the actual code :p

Comment: You can initialize `hash` to contain all the keys from `1` to `numbersrange`, with initial values `0`. Then the `0` entries will be in there.

Comment: @Barmar I want to add the numbers that only occurred 0 and 1 times to the output, so it matches the desired output depicted above. The "numbersrange" variable is to define the max range that numbers go up to, as depicted in example 2 and 1. This ensures that the results will not be infinite. I could not see how to integrate the numbersrange variable correctly so it is not in the code yet.

Comment: @JaromandaX I added additional clarification above ^^

Comment: edited snippet to show the correct number of sections which is 3 to match the current outputs described and depicted above.

Comment: Why do you have a `.filter()` that only returns the number that occurred more than 1 if you wanted to include them?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. You're missing one thing and you have one unnecessary `filter`.

Missing: You need to create a map of numbers (1 to `numbersrange`) before you do the counting. Or else, the numbers with 0 occurrences won't show up. I've done it like this

```
const mapOfNumbers = new Array(numbersrange + 1).fill(0).reduce((acc, _, i) => (acc[i] = 0, acc), {});
delete mapOfNumbers[0];
```

Extra: The `.filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)` is not required as you want `1` and `0` occurrences as well.

```js
//Count how many times each number shows up

//const duplicateArr2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23];
//const duplicateArr1 = [5, 3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 7, 3, 2];
//const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54];
//const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54,100,100,200,200,300,300];

//const duplicateArr2 = searchednumbers;
const duplicateArr2 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5]

const getArrayOfDuplicated = (array, numbersrange) => {
  const mapOfNumbers = new Array(numbersrange + 1).fill(0).reduce((acc, _, i) => (acc[i] = 0, acc), {});
  delete mapOfNumbers[0];
  const hash = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1, a), mapOfNumbers);
  return Object.entries(hash)
    .sort(([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => bv - av)
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, `${k} - ${v} times`], [])
};

// given a number of items to be sectioned into a certain number of groups
// returns a list of length nGroups with the number of items in each group
// such that at least (nGroups - 1) groups contain an equal number of items
// eg. getGrouping(10, 2) -> [5, 5]
// eg. getGrouping(10, 6) -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
const getGrouping = (nItems, nGroups) => {
  if (nGroups > nItems)
    return Array(nItems).fill(1);
  else if (!(nItems % nGroups))
    return Array(nGroups).fill(parseInt(nItems / nGroups));
  else {
    let numberOfEqualGroups = nGroups - 1;
    var itemsPerEqualGroup;
    if (!(nItems % (nGroups - 1)))
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1)) - 1;
    else
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1));
    equalGroups = Array(numberOfEqualGroups).fill(parseInt(itemsPerEqualGroup));
    remainder = nItems - itemsPerEqualGroup * numberOfEqualGroups;
    return equalGroups.concat(remainder);
  }
}

// takes an array and formats it into sections according to grouping
// returns a string with a newline after each line and two new lines between sections
const formatGrouping = (array, grouping) => {
  var outputString = ""
  var linesDone = 0;
  for (var section = 0; section < grouping.length; section++) {
    for (var line = 0; line < grouping[section]; line++) {
      outputString += array[linesDone] + '<br>';
      linesDone += 1;
    }
    outputString += '<br>';
  }
  return outputString;
};

var numberOfSections = 3;
var numbersrange = 9;
result = getArrayOfDuplicated(duplicateArr2, numbersrange);
document.getElementById("jsresultsoutput").innerHTML = formatGrouping(result, getGrouping(result.length, numberOfSections));
```

```html
<p id="jsresultsoutput"></p>
```

Also, reading the comments on your question will give you the complete solution that you're missing. You can say I've compiled the comments into a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't follow OP code very well but understood the objectives:

1. Input is an array of numbers of an arbitrary length -- each number within the range of 1 to `n`.
2. The output are groups of the following:

   - **Excluded** numbers that were not included in the input array but is within the given range.
   - **Unique** numbers that were included in the input array and within the given range.
   - **Duplicated** numbers that were included in the input array and within the given range.
3. Each group of duplicates must be listed with its total quantity as well.

---

Instead of generating DOM for every number, I have developed a form that clearly defines required parameters in a logical flow. Constraints and values are as follows:

- User sets the min/max values of the number range. Minimum value can be set to [`1` - `99`] / maximum value can be set to [`minimum value +1` - `100`].
- Next user can add any amount of numbers by entering the value and clicking the <kbd>Add</kbd> button. Should the user enter a number that exceeds the established range, the input is automatically capped to the max/min values accordingly.
- Finally the user clicks the <kbd>Sort</kbd> button. The last 4 fields will display the output (**2.** thru **4.** have been described previously):

  **1. Input Array** displays the numbers as an ordered array.

  **2. Excluded**, **3. Unique**, **4. Duplicated**
- The user can go back to adding additional numbers to the results or start over by clicking the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button or by simply setting a new range.

---

Although using on-event attributes is frowned upon because of their inherent limitations -- using on-event attributes on a form to associate inputs with outputs, providing proper behavior and constraints, etc. is actually advantageous. `oninput`, `onchange`, and `onclick` are there for user interaction and is only marginally involved with the main functions.

Just a quick outline on the functions:

- The references to the `<form>` and its form controls (ie `input`, `output`, `button`, and `fieldset`) are made possible with **HTMLFormElement** and **HTMLFormControlsCollection** interfaces. The syntax is terse and the range of elements are optimal:

  > ```
  >  document.getElementById('formID').querySelectorAll('input, button, select, textarea, output, fieldset');
  > ```

  ## vs.

  > ```
  >  document.forms.formID.elements;
  > ```
- The range of numbers is provided by a generator function (`*generateRange()`) which returns an array of consecutive numbers between the given min and max values (inclusive).
- Then once the range array is generated, it is ran through a `for...of` loop. On each iteration, the current number is `.set()` to an ES6 `Map()` as a key with a value of: `0`.
- Next the input array is ran thru a `for...of` loop. On each iteration the number is found in the `Map()` as a key then the associated value is increased by 1.
- With very little effort we have a `Map()` that has every number within the given range as a key with either a value of `0` (**Excluded**), `1` (**Unique**), or `2+` (**Duplicated**).
- and at last, the groups are displayed in the form.

```js
const ui = document.forms[0].elements;

const stringToNumber = str => parseInt(str, 10);

const isNumber = val => Number(parseFloat(val)) === val;

function* generateRange(min, max) {
  while (min < max) {
    yield min;
    min += 1;
  }
}

const displayRange = map => {
  let outputs = Array.from(ui.data);
  for (let i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
    outputs[i].textContent = '';
  }
  for (let [number, count] of map.entries()) {
    if (count === 0) {
      ui.zero.textContent += `${number} `;
    } else if (count === 1) {
      ui.one.textContent += `${number} `;
    } else {
      ui.more.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<label>
${number}: ${count} times</label>`);
    }
  }
}

const clearData = e => {
  const fields = e.currentTarget.elements.data;
  for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].textContent = '';
  }
}
const addNumber = e => {
  let number = e.target.previousElementSibling.valueAsNumber;
  if (number > ui.max.valueAsNumber) {
    number = ui.max.valueAsNumber;
  } else if (number < ui.min.valueAsNumber) {
    number = ui.min.valueAsNumber;
  } else {
    number = number;
  }
  ui.input.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', ` ${number} `);
}

const sortArray = e => {
  let string = ui.input.textContent;
  let numbers = string.split(' ').map(stringToNumber).filter(num => isNumber(num));
  let array = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let min = ui.min.valueAsNumber;
  let max = ui.max.valueAsNumber + 1;
  let range = Array.from(generateRange(min, max));
  let map = new Map();
  for (let r of range) {
    map.set(r, 0);
  }
  for (let a of array) {
    map.set(a, (map.get(a) + 1));
  }
  ui.array.textContent = '';
  ui.array.textContent = JSON.stringify(array);
  return displayRange(map);
}

ui.add.onclick = addNumber;
ui.sort.onclick = sortArray;
document.forms[0].onreset = clearData;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1 Consolas;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5vh 3vw 10vh 0;
}

main {
  width: 96vw;
  height: auto;
}

#freq {
  width: 98%;
}

output,
input,
button,
label {
  font: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4vh;
}

#input,
#array,
#zero,
#one,
#more {
  min-height: 60px;
  height: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#range input {
  width: 30%;
}

#range output {
  width: 3ch;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#num {
  text-align: center;
  width: 5ch;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

#numbers input,
#numbers button {
  margin-bottom: 8px
}

#sort,
[type=reset],
sub {
  float: right;
}

button {
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#more label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id='freq' oninput='max.min = min.valueAsNumber+1; maxOut.value = max.value;' onchange='num.min = min.value; num.max = max.value'>
    <fieldset id='range' onclick="num.value = ''; input.textContent = ''; array.textContent = ''; zero.textContent = ''; one.textContent = ''; more.textContent = '';">
      <legend>Define Number Range</legend>
      <label for='min'>Min: </label><input id='min' type='range' min='1' max='99' oninput='minOut.value = this.value;' value='1'><output id='minOut' for='min num'>1</output>
      <label for='max'>Max: </label><input id='max' type='range' max='100' oninput='maxOut.value = this.value'><output id='maxOut' for='max num'></output>
      <sub>min: 1 / max: 100</sub>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='numbers'>
      <legend>Add &amp; Sort Numbers</legend>
      <input id='num' type='number'>
      <button id='add' type='button'>Add</button>
      <button type='reset'>Clear</button>
      <button id='sort' type='button'>Sort</button>
      <fieldset>
        <output id='input' name='data'></output>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='output'>
      <legend>Output</legend>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Input Array</legend>
        <output id='array' name='data'></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Excluded</legend>
        <output id='zero' name='data'></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Unique</legend>
        <output id='one' name='data'></output>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Duplicated</legend>
        <output id='more' name='data'></output>
      </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```